# How to prove the complexity of T(n)=T(n-1)+log n =Θ(nlog n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How can I prove that
T(n)=T(n-1)+log n = Θ(nlog(n))

### My thinking:

We can get T(n)=∑log(n). To prove the result, We have to prove both ∑log(n)>=Nlog(N) and ∑log(n)<=Nlog(N). The second is easy, I want to know how to prove ∑log(n)>=Nlog(N)?

Answer (score 2):

Assume `N > 10`. (You only need to prove the bound for "large enough" `N`.)

Suppose we have `sum_n log(n)` but we ignore the terms where `n < N/10`.
We have `9/10 * N` terms left, and each term is at least `log(N/10)`. Then:

`sum_n log(n) >= (9/10 * N) * log(N/10)
               = (9/10 * N) * (log(N) - log(10))
               = (constant) * N * log(N) - (constant) * N`

which is clearly `Omega(N log N)`.